# Strange behavior in Google Chrome with vertical scroll

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar

I'm developing a website and came across some strange behavior in Google Chrome. I test with the latest versions of Chrome, IE, FireFox, Opera and Safari.

Visit this link: http://www.houseofsynergy.com/, wait for it to load and them single-click anywhere on the page. A vertical scroll bar will appear even though the page clearly does not need scrolling. Of course this is only applicable if your monitor is large enough to view the whole page in. I don't see this happening with any of the other 4 browsers.

At times before, a single click has caused an out of place square to appear outside of the content area. Is there something wrong with the HTML?

The page is: DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional with CSS3 using only divs on most pages.

Comment: Clicking seems to expand the `<body>` by a fixed amount. So some really short pages will not get the scroll bar. You can notice the difference by tracking the background towards the bottom. I have left a minor inconsistency in a repeated background image so you can just barely tell what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange. It seems like one of the extensions is to blame. The issue disappears when in incognito mode.

Google Dictionary seems to be the culprit. It allows you to double click words to pull up meanings and the `<div>` it inserts is not configured properly.